# How to set proxy without credentials to WebClient c.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, proxy, webclient, port

I have a proxy and port number but don't have credentials .how can iset the webclient to go through that proxy ,the below code is giving error

```
string proxyserver = "http://10.0.0.127:8080/";
    IWebProxy proxy = new WebProxy(proxyserver);
    proxy.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
    WebClient.Proxy = proxy;
     byte[] rawResponse = WebClient.UploadFile(url, filename);
```

If i use CredentialCache i don't have authenticationtype and networkcredential. Is there any other way to assign my proxy to the WebClient

thanks,

michaled

Comment: _'the below code is giving error'_ - And, the error is?

Comment: @  Mr. Disappointment  : the remote server returned an error 403 Forbidden , without the proxy i am able to hit the destination url don't know what is wrong with proxy. can i set proxy with proxy.GetProxy() ?

Comment: Your code example is incomplete.  What is Client?  A web client or your own class?  Please include a stack trace of your error and a better code snippet.

Comment: yes it is WebClient and edited in code

Answer (score 0):

Unless the code you have supplied is only a portion of your actual code, you will need to associate the proxy created with the WebClient object using the Proxy property (See documentation below):

[WebClient.Proxy Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient.proxy.aspx)

If you are already doing so then disregard this.

Comment: if i set like this  WebProxy proxy = new WebProxy();  proxy.GetProxy(proxyserver); i am getting address null but going through proxy don't know whether it is hitting proxy or not.

Comment: You are creating a proxy, but you don't pass the proxy along to WebClient at any point in the code so WebClient doesn't know to use it.

Comment: As Jesper mentions above you need to assign the proxy object to the WebClient using the Proxy property I described in my answer (WebClient.Proxy = proxy;)

Comment: WebClient.Proxy = proxy; it is in the code, but as said above address prop of proxy is null ,what property is  exactly our proxyaddress ?